# How do I forward from one local port to another local port on OS X?

Tags: mysql, networking

I have a MySQL instance running locally on port 3306, but for some legacy apps I also want to make it available on port 3305 (don't ask). Is there an easy way to do this on OS X, so that if I try to connect on either 3305 or 3306 they will both go to the MySQL server on 3306?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ipfw to set up a forwarding rule for port 3305 to send it to port 3306.

```
ipfw add fwd localhost,3306 tcp from any to any 3305 via en0
```

My syntax might be a little off and you may have to change it to the actual IP address or add a second rule for it.

Comment: I had to use lo0 because it was local, but the rest works brilliantly. Thanks for that!